# Can't clear the setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to clear the interval when stop button is clicked it seems the `clearInterval` is not working there as expected. The timer doesn't stop when `handleStop` function is triggered or when `handleReset` id triggered

Here's  what I am trying to do:

```
import React from "react"
import useApp from "../App"
import Interact from "./Interact";

const Timer = () => {
    
    let timer;
    const {millisec , setMillisec , sec , setSec , min , setMin , hr , setHr} = useApp();
    const handleStart = () => {
     timer =  setInterval(() => {
          setMillisec((prev) => {
            if (prev === 100) {
              setSec((prevB) =>{
                if(prevB === 60){
                    setMin(prevC => {
                        if(prevC === 60){
                            setHr(prevD => prevD + 1)
                            return 0
                        } 
                        return prevC + 1
                    })
                    return 0
                }
             return prevB + 1
            });
              return 0;
            }
            return prev + 1;
          });
        }, 10);

       

      };
    const handleStop = () => {
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
    
    const handleReset = () => {
            clearInterval(timer)
        setMillisec(0)
        setSec(0)
        setMin(0)
        setHr(0)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div className="parent">
                <div className="main">
                    <h1 className="heading">Stop Watch</h1>
                    <div className="timer">
                    <div className ="hour">{hr}</div>
                    <div className ="min">{min}</div>
                    <div className ="sec">{sec}</div>
                    <div className ="millisec">{millisec}</div>
                    </div>
                    <Interact handleStart = {handleStart} 
                              handleStop = {handleStop} 
                              handleReset ={handleReset}
                              />
                </div>
            </div>
           
            
        </>
    )
}
export default Timer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable `timer` re-declare every time when Timer component rendered. Thus, the setInterval reference is reset.

You can declare timer at global scope, like

```
...
import Interact from "./Interact";

let timer;
const Timer = () => {    
    const {millisec , setMillisec , sec , setSec , min , setMin , hr , setHr} = useApp();
    const handleStart = () => {
...
```

or can also use react-hooks to maintain setInterwal reference. like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: Just be aware that this means that you can have only a single `<Timer />`

Answer (score -1):

Pass your setInterval() to a clearInterval() when you need to break it.

Comment: That's what I did by storing setInterval in a variable called timer and then passing timer to clearInterval() but it's not working.